# Sorting List by DateTime

Tags: c#

I have tried the solutions I have found and cannot seem to make this work for me.

I have a class:

```
public class InvokeGetReportRequestListResponse
{
    public MarketplaceWebServiceException Error { get; set; }
    public bool CallStatus { get; set; }
    public List<RequestedReport> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class RequestedReport
{
    public String ReportRequestId;
    public String ReportType;
    public DateTime? StartDate;
    public DateTime? EndDate;
    public Boolean Scheduled;
    public DateTime? SubmittedDate;
    public String ReportProcessingStatus;
    public String GeneratedReportId;
    public DateTime? StartedProcessingDate;
    public DateTime? CompletedDate;
}
```

I make a call to a service:

```
InvokeGetReportRequestListResponse callResponse = InvokeGetReportRequestList(callRequest);
```

And now I want to sort the `Reports` list in `callResponse` by `CompletedDate`

`callResponse.Reports.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.CompletedDate, y.CompletedDate));`

This returns an error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<WebFeeds.Amazon.API.DataTypes.RequestedReport>' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: what's the .NET framework version you are using? this code should work fine in .Net 4 and above

Comment: VS2012 target framework 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting can be done using Linq via the following statement.

```
var Result = callResponse.Report.OrderBy( iItem => iItem.CompletedDate );
```

Comment: This is the way I thought I would go but `callResponse.Report` has no `OrderBy` method.

Comment: Please show the definition of `InvokeRepoerRequestListResponse`.

Comment: @Fred have you using `System.Linq`?

Comment: @pwas Thank you! I cant believe I missed that.